# What is the meaning of "only to have instead one nail snap off" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

> The claws scraped at a cloak they should have readily tattered, **only to have instead one nail snap off**.
>   [Warcraft: War of the Ancients #1]

The structure looks strange and I didn't ever see "instead" in the position like this.

Comment: It is "one nail"

Comment: Sorry, I edited it

Comment: The **instead** can occur in several places without loss of meaning. The phrase means that a nail had **unexpectedly fallen off** when it should have been stronger.

Comment: Is there any structure for this? Or can you explain "only to have instead" more detail? Thank you

Comment: @vietphi I think maybe the main part of the sentence confused you. (I'm sorry if you can understand it clearly already.) The sentence can be trimmed down to *The claws scraped at a cloak they should have readily tattered* (i.e., without the "only to have ..." part) without mush loss in meaning.

Comment: Technically speaking it's "grammatical", but it's a *terrible* example of written English - even worse than [the clumsy use of "latter"](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/77556/) in your other question. In this case, transitive *to tatter* is rare/obsolete, and *readily (willingly)*  is only marginally acceptable with a "non-sentient" subject like *claws*. But the worst aspect is that the surface parallelism of *should have X, only to have Y* doesn't work because ***have*** is performing different syntactic/semantic functions. My advice: don't use text like this to learn English.

Comment: *Readily* has both volitional and non-volitional uses.  In this case it's non-volitional, and there's no problem with it.  I agree the sentence sounds clumsy, and the biggest problem is the position of *instead*.  It would be much more natural if *instead* were moved to the end of the sentence, as TRomano suggests in his answer.  I agree that *tattered* is unusual, but it's readily understandable.  If you just fix *instead*, the sentence sounds considerably better.

Answer (score 4):

You are right to sense some strangeness here.  There are two patterns being awkwardly combined.

> Instead of tattering the cloak, one of the nails broke.

"Only to have..." is used when someone is disappointed or thwarted, so there should be a *sentient being*  (a noun capable of *having*, i.e. experiencing) in the main clause:

> *He* scraped with the claws, which should have readily tattered the
>   cloak, only to have one of the nails break off.

The original sentence, in combining "instead" and "only to have", and in leaving out the sentient being, is something of a mess.

If the claws in this game are a sentient creature, that might explain the use of "only to have".  Are they sentient?

P.S. OK, as it turns out,"the claws" is a creature.  So we could say:

> The Claws scraped at the cloak, which it should have readily tattered,
>   only to have one of its nails snap off.

"Instead" could be placed at the end of that sentence (..."one of its nails snap off instead").

Comment: It is an imagined creature that has claws thank you.

Comment: @vietphi: so the creature called "the claws" has volition? It can go where it wants to go and it can make choices?

Comment: yes, it is sth like a tiger, lion... But has many eyes and others thing

Answer (score 2):

In your example, **instead** is used for **contrast**.
The expectation is that the **claw** would normally **tear** the cloak with little effort (**scraped**)

**Instead** can be used in several different places without loss of meaning

> only to have **instead**
>   **instead** only to have
>   only **instead** to have

it has the contrasting meaning of **but**

> **but** a nail fell off

the meaning being the nails on the claws were not as strong as **expected**

> The *(nails on the)* claws **should have** easily ripped the cloak apart **but** they **did not**, and **as a result** *(of trying to rip the cloak)* one nail fell off

The general structure is

> *something was expected/supposed to happen* **instead** *something else happened*
>
> I was supposed to fly to London today, **instead** the flight was cancelled.
>   I paid for a coffee, **instead** I got tea.

Comment: By the way, why is it using "only to have" instead of "only one snail snap off"

Answer (score 0):

To add to the answers on the *content* of the sentence, the *structure* of the sentence is a bit unusual.

Word order in English sentences is flexible, and unusual sentence structure can be used to draw emphasis to a word or phrase, among other purposes; the most common is [**inversion**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/inversion)