# Is this word "precariously" add meaning to the first of the sentence or else?

Tags: adverbs, comparative-constructions, participle-phrases

> The tall, forbidding palace perched atop the very edge of the mountainous cliff, overlooking so **precariously** the vast, black body of water below that it appeared almost ready to plummet into the latter's dark depths. [Warcraft War of the Ancients #1]

Does the word "precariously" add any meaning to "the vast" for "The Forbidding palace"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word "precariously" is adding to the word "overlooking" in the combined phrase "overlooking so precariously", which then links to the later part of the sentence making the meaning "overlooking so precariously ... that it appeared almost ready to plummet". The use of the phrase "the latter" is used to indicate the twist in the word ordering. "the latter" means "the thing I just wrote earlier", which is the "vast black body of water".

Comment: I submitted the whole sentence but not sure the latter have some meaning related.

Comment: @vietphi - I amended my answer to match your corrected text

Comment: Your answer make me understand but the structure like this was so confused and I wonder "the vast" has any meaning in the sentence? Is it "looking precarious to the vast"?

Comment: @vietphi - It is the black body of water which is vast

Answer (score 2):

**Precariously** is a modifier for **perched**. **Precariously** means **questionably unstable**.  Things that are **precariously** placed have a higher possibility of **falling down**.

> The books were stacked **precariously** on top each other.

The reason why the palace was **precariously overlooking** was because of how the palace was **placed on the edge of a cliff**.

**Precarious** could also have a different meaning

> The circumstances surrounding what he saw were **precarious**...

which means

> The various conditions which allowed him to see *something* **unusually aligned** and were changable

But that would not apply in your example, since the palace's view was not obtained by a **chance coincidence of events**, its location was **planned**.

Comment: I did mean it as **dependent on chance** as opposed to **by chance or coincidence** which is more **seredipity**. I've editted my answer which is hopefully clearer